# Magento Grid appears on the top of page and does not respond

Tags: php, magento, grid

I have a working grid in magento for a custom module and finally has been displayed on the admin panel. I couldn't trace the reason why it is displayed on the top.

[image]

I have written the below code in controller...

[image]

The grid does not even respond to my mouse clicks..

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the path /magento1.9.2/app/code/local/Namespace/Module Name/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Grid.php

just remove the getGridUrl function

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
   return $this->getUrl(*/*/Grid,array('_current')=>true));
}
```

the above code will return the Grid action..if you want to keep this function just rename the */*/Grid to your indexAction or your first Action.